# Java spark to hive table insertion to dynamic partition exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have the following code in which I am inserting data to table `txnaggr_rt_fact` which is having 2 columns are partitioned `txninterval` and `intervaltype`. I have enabled dynamic partition in spark sql. If the partition already exists there is no problem.

The data is getting inserted to the table but if the partition doesn't exist then an exception arises but if the partition already exists then there is no problem.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse")
                .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
        spark.sql("use nadb");
        spark.sql("show tables").show();
        spark.sql("insert into table txnaggr_rt_fact partition(txninterval='2018-09-03',intervaltype='test') values('1','2','3',4)"); //(Line number 113) Exception raises here as partition doesn't exist
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadPartition(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
        at com.cw.na.spark.HiveSqlTest.main(HiveSqlTest.java:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.replaceFiles(Hive.java:3412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadPartition(Hive.java:1579)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadPartition(HiveShim.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:209)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadPartition(HiveClientImpl.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:855)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadPartition$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:843)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        ... 25 more
```

I am using `hive metastore` service as well by using `hive --service metastore`

I have the following properties in the spark conf folder of `hive-site.xml`

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Whether or not to allow dynamic partitions in DML/DDL.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
    <value>nonstrict</value>
    <description>
      In strict mode, the user must specify at least one static partition
      in case the user accidentally overwrites all partitions.
      In nonstrict mode all partitions are allowed to be dynamic.
    </description>
  </property>
```

This property `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode` is set to `strict` and after realization I have changed it to `nonstrict`. I didn't restart spark afterwards but I have stopped the metastore and started it. Do I need to restart spark as well. What else am I missing here in my code?

Following is the schema of the txnaggr_rt_fact:

```
channelid               string
chaincodeid             string
chaincodefcn            string
count                   int
txninterval             date
intervaltype            string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

txninterval             date
intervaltype            string
```

Need help.
Thanks

Comment: what is the schema of `txnaggr_rt_fact`? maybe the number of values in the list of inserted values is different from the number of columns

Comment: Following is the schema and I am inserting accordingly
`channelid               string
chaincodeid             string
chaincodefcn            string
count                   int
txninterval             date
intervaltype            string

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

txninterval             date
intervaltype            string`

Comment: if you're sure that the exception drops due to the absense of partition (it's not obvious by looking at the logs though), how about using `alter table add if not exists partition (txninterval=<value>, intervaltype=<value>)` before inserting?

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much. It worked. Please add this as answer I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks alot for your time. This saved me

Comment: don't worry about that, glad that it worked

Comment: Please add this as answer below. It might be helpful for someone like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you're sure about the reason being the absense of inserted partition, you may issue the following query prior to inserting your data:

```
alter table add if not exists partition (txninterval=<value>, intervaltype=<value>)
```